# Convert Object to Array PHP - only public fields

Tags: php, oop, object

I want to convert an object to array in PHP - but only public fields of it. I found some answers already about casting object to array in PHP, but they all convert all the fields (also private). I need only public fields though - how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By using [get_object_vars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Example:

```
$object_to_arr = get_object_vars($obj);
```

`get_object_vars()` will only return accessible and non-static properties of the object.

**Edit:**

If you're running this directly on `$this` then it will return `private` properties. This is because even `private` properties are accessible to the class itself.

To get around this, do something like:

```
$i = $this; 
$publics_only = function() use ($i) { 
    return get_object_vars($i); 
}; 
return $publics_only();
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed that one.

Comment: I would add serialize if OP is attempting to store such properties somewhere
 http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: @AlanChavez that's the same with any array. It's up to the OP to handle the array in the necessary way.

Comment: Tbh it seems I serialized also with private fields when I used it on `$this`... I guess I won't be able to use inside a method.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your anwser Ryan. I cant check it now but I belive your answer is for PHP 5.4+. I know what you had in mind and I think I'll manage to do that in 5.2 ;-)

Comment: @KeluThatsall the `use` identifier is 5.3+, but you can do it without that.

Comment: ye ill just use `create_function`

Comment: Since PHP 5.4.0, the second way, with anonymous function, will also return private properties.